# Как сохранить сущности в бд используя разные транкзации

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть следующий метод:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newCard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCard(@Valid @ModelAttribute("cardForm") Cards card, @RequestParam("balance") String balance,
                       BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    card.setTypeCard(typeCardService.getTypeCardbyStatus("active"));
    cardService.saveCard(card);
    CardBalance cardBalance = new CardBalance();
    cardBalance.setBalance(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(balance)));
    cardBalance.setCardId(card.getCardId());
    cardBalanceService.save(cardBalance);
    return "success";
}
```

Здесь я сохраняю Card в бд, а затем пытаюсь сохранить баланс для этой карты. Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь сохранить баланс карты, я получаю ошибку - "родительская таблица не существует" (кард-баланс ссылается на кард). Полагаю, что все это происходит из-за того, что всё выполняется в одной транзакции. Подскажите как эту проблему можно разрешить?

Лог:

```
    type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [NICK.FK_CARD_ID_HIST]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [NICK.FK_CARD_ID_HIST]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
root cause

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [NICK.FK_CARD_ID_HIST]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:241)
...
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (NICK.FK_CARD_ID_HIST) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at "NICK.ONEINTOHIST", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'NICK.ONEINTOHIST'
```

Comment: Вам прямо пишут, что проблема в отсутствии таблицы, транзакции здесь ни при чем.

Comment: посмотрите, я добавил лог. Там написано что родительский ключ не найден

Comment: Эт совсем другое, да, такое может возникнуть при разных транзакциях, но по идее гибернейт должен взять на себя сохранение связанных сущностей

Comment: Да разобрался, проблема была в том, что id карты выдается c помощью БД - триггером, а я пытался в приложении получить id когда там null. Короче костыль написал)